# troubleshooting a hello world module

Tags: magento-1.7

I followed a tutorial from [Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world) on creating a basic Hello World module for Magento. After some initial problems I got it working. Today I have gone to try and expand on that and the module no longer works(I get a 404 page not found message), I have not changed any code within that module or deleted any files.

The only thing that I can think I did since first creating the module and now is go into Magento's admin screen and make some adjustments - which i've tried changing back, but I still get the 404. I also have few other basic modules that I have been working on, but they also seem to no longer work.

I have checked System > Configuration > Advanced and the modules are all still enabled

Can anyone see something in my code that would stop this module from not being found when I vist http://magentotest.local/helloworld

app/etc/modules/As_Helloworld.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <As_Helloworld>
            <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
        </As_Helloworld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/As/Helloworld/controllers/IndexController.php

```
class As_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{        
    public function indexAction() {
        echo 'Hello Index!';
}
}
```

app/code/local/As/Helloworld/etc/config.xml

```
<config> 
    <modules>
        <As_Helloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </As_Helloworld>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>As_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>    
</config>
```

1-Would changing options in the admin area be able to stop a module working?

2-If so where do I start looking to fix the problem

3-What can I do to prevent it from happening again?

Comment: Just in case, it's still enabled in Admin, under System > Configuration > Advanced?

Comment: I have looked at that and it is still enabled, I shall add that to my post, as it is a valid point, thanks

Comment: No problem, just figured I'd ask about the low-hanging fruit first. Also make sure it's also enabled for the website, store, view, etc.

Comment: checked that too, its really annoying me